# Better algorithm for complementing integer value excluding the leading zero binary bits

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, complement

I will explain first what I mean by "complementing integer value excluding the leading zero binary bits" (from now on, I will call it Non Leading Zero Bits complement or NLZ-Complement for brevity).

For example, there is integer number 92. the binary number is 1011100. If we perform normal bitwise-NOT or Complement, the result is: -93 (signed integer) or 11111111111111111111111110100011 (binary). That's because the leading zero bits are being complemented too.

So, for NLZ-Complement, the leading zero bits are not complemented, then the result of NLZ-complementing of 92 or 1011100 is: 35 or 100011 (binary). The operation is performed by XORing the input value with sequence of 1 bits as much as the non-leading zero value. The illustration:

```
92:  1011100
     1111111 (xor)
     --------
     0100011 => 35
```

I had made the java algorithm like this:

```
public static int nonLeadingZeroComplement(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return ~n;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    //This line is to find how much the non-leading zero (NLZ) bits count.
    //This operation is same like: ceil(log2(n))
    int binaryBitsCount = Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n - 1);

    //We use the NLZ bits count to generate sequence of 1 bits as much as the NLZ bits count as complementer
    //by using shift left trick that equivalent to: 2 raised to power of binaryBitsCount.
    //1L is one value with Long literal that used here because there is possibility binaryBitsCount is 32
    //(if the input is -1 for example), thus it will produce 2^32 result whom value can't be contained in 
    //java signed int type.
    int oneBitsSequence = (int)((1L << binaryBitsCount) - 1);

    //XORing the input value with the sequence of 1 bits
    return n ^ oneBitsSequence;
}
```

I need an advice how to optimize above algorithm, especially the line for generating sequence of 1 bits complementer (oneBitsSequence), or if anyone can suggest better algorithm?

**UPDATE:** I also would like to know the known term of this non-leading zero complement?

Comment: So for all powers of two you want to return 0. So starting from 0 the sequence would be 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 6, ... What is the use of this?

Comment: What you call "NLZ-Complement" is what is known as Ones' Complement. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One%27s_compliment

Comment: @MisterSmith: are you sure? I think it's not. One's complement also complements the leading zeroes.

Comment: In that case, you are right. Will update my answer.

Comment: After some thinking, seems that you have to count the leading 0's. So instead of editing my wrong answer, I'll delete it, since the first answer is the correct.

Comment: It's ok, I'm still open to other alternatives. I'm also curious what's the known term of this complement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the highest one bit through the `Integer.highestOneBit(i)` method, shift this one step left, and then subtract 1. This gets you the correct length of `1`s:

```
private static int nonLeadingZeroComplement(int i) {
    int ones = (Integer.highestOneBit(i) << 1) - 1;
    return i ^ ones;
}
```

For example,

```
System.out.println(nonLeadingZeroComplement(92));
```

prints

```
35
```

Comment: I knew it! There must be a built-in function that can make this more simple. Lol, you make this very easy. Do you know the real/known term of this NLZ-complement?

Comment: @suud: No, sorry, I don't know a special term for this.

Answer (score 2):

obviously @keppil has provided shortest solution. Another solution could be like.

```
private static int integerComplement(int n){

  String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(n);

  String temp = "";
  for(char c: binaryString.toCharArray()){
      if(c == '1'){
          temp += "0";
      }
      else{
          temp += "1";
      }
  }
  int base = 2;
  int complement = Integer.parseInt(temp, base);

  return complement;
}
```

For example,

```
System.out.println(nonLeadingZeroComplement(92));
```

Prints answer as 35